# Access the Keycloak admin console with an access token

Tags: keycloak

My App gets an *access token* that can be used to manage keycloak resources.

I can add this token as a header `Authorization`:`Bearer {token}` to a GET-request to the userinfo-endpoint: `{server}/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` and it works correct.

However, if I add this header to GET-requests to the admin-console `{server}/auth/admin/{realm}/console/#/realms/{realm}`, I am always redirected to the login page.

Is it possible to access admin-console only with the access-token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak admin console e.g. `{server}/auth/admin/{realm}/console/#/realms/{realm}` is a single page application (SPA), so it has own "state" in the browser.

Page itself is not protected (anyone can load it for example via curl - it is just a bunch of css and js files). SPA app loaded into browser detects that it doesn't have login state, so it inititializes own login procedure, which then create login state in the browser. You can't recreate that SPA login state in the browser only from the access token. You will need to recreate all cookies, session variables, maybe also some in-memory variables, so in real world it isn't possible.

Generally, in this case: access token is for API requests, not UI requests.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak has an admin REST API. https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html

You can use that API to manipulate keycloak in the same way the admin console (the javascript app at {server}/auth/admin/{realm}/console/) does.